# What calls Controller class's methods in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

A general question in MVC. We know, in order to call a method, an object need to be created for the class containing the method and call then call it with that object.

My question is, in MVC we only define the default controller name and 'ActionResult' in route config.

Now what is creating object for that controller class and calling method(ActionResult) with that object?

Comment: It's the MVC framework. Every Controller class gets initialized once, then just the methods get called. If you need to resolve something, have a look to Dependency Injection.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate reply. I will look into Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the MVC framework itself. Based on the route, method etc it's supposed to handle, it will instantiate a particular controller class and invoke the specified method/s for it to handle that route.